Package 'gettext' has no installation candidate, but package exists
This isn't only happening with gettext. There are a bunch of packages that I cannot install. It gives me this error:
sudo apt install gettext

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Package gettext is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'gettext' has no installation candidate

However, this package clearly exists for my distro, Ubuntu 22.04. I already ran sudo apt update and that doesn't solve the issue.
Also, my /etc/apt/sources.list seems fine.
cat /etc/apt/sources.list
# deb cdrom:[Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS _Jammy Jellyfish_ - Release amd64 (20230807.2)]/ jammy main restricted

# See http://help.ubuntu.com/community/UpgradeNotes for how to upgrade to
# newer versions of the distribution.
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy restricted
# deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy main restricted

## Major bug fix updates produced after the final release of the
## distribution.
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy-updates restricted
# deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy-updates main restricted

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu
## team. Also, please note that software in universe WILL NOT receive any
## review or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy universe
# deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy universe
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy-updates universe
# deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy-updates universe

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu
## team, and may not be under a free licence. Please satisfy yourself as to
## your rights to use the software. Also, please note that software in
## multiverse WILL NOT receive any review or updates from the Ubuntu
## security team.
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy multiverse
# deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy multiverse
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy-updates multiverse
# deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy-updates multiverse

## N.B. software from this repository may not have been tested as
## extensively as that contained in the main release, although it includes
## newer versions of some applications which may provide useful features.
## Also, please note that software in backports WILL NOT receive any review
## or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy-backports restricted universe multiverse
# deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy-backports main restricted universe multiverse

deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security restricted
# deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security main restricted
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security universe
# deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security universe
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security multiverse
# deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security multiverse

# This system was installed using small removable media
# (e.g. netinst, live or single CD). The matching "deb cdrom"
# entries were disabled at the end of the installation process.
# For information about how to configure apt package sources,
# see the sources.list(5) manual.

My system:
uname -a
Linux queenie 6.5.0-21-generic #21~22.04.1-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Fri Feb  9 13:32:52 UTC 2 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux



Also, my /etc/apt/sources.list seems fine.

No it's not. Your sources.list is missing a vital component - the Main repo.
You should add the main component to these lines in /etc/apt/sources.list:
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy main restricted
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates main restricted
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security main restricted
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-backports main restricted


Thank you!! I have no clue how my apt sources suddenly got into this state. I haven't edited this file at all, but this issue just suddenly appeared.

@AndyCarlson FYI: If your system is a desktop system, the is a GUI way of removing the main repository (ie. see https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Repositories/Ubuntu and the first picture on that page) where its possible it was done via click of that checkbox, rather than via a direct edit.
